# Удаление реакции пользователя discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord

Мне нужен код, который будет удалять реакции пользователя в определенном канале, то есть если пользователь поставил реакцию под сообщеним, то удалить её. Но я ни как не могу совместить on_raw_reaction_add и remove_reaction.
Вот код который я использую

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self,message):
        if message.channel_id == "762253503388450839":
 
        
   bot.remove_reaction(message.channel_id,message.message_id,message.name,message.user_id)

client = MyClient()
client.run('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

И да, почему-то в строчке bot.remove_reaction, ставится перенос строки, ставится он когда я пишу на форуме, когда я выполняю код, всё нормально
Этот код выводит ошибку, как это можно пофиксить, и достичь нужного результата?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это точно работает, id канала замени на свой. На клиенте никогда не работал, так что только так.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channelid = payload.channel_id
    user = payload.member
    messageid = payload.message_id
    if channelid == 676489052584804365:
        channel = bot.get_channel(channelid)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(messageid)
        for reaction in message.reactions:
            await reaction.remove(user)
    else:
        return
```